# How to correct a CoreData migration that is missing some attributes?

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration, magicalrecord-2.2

I performed a lightweight migration using MagicalRecord on my previous xcdatamodel which was successfully migrated. Now, I need to add several new attributes; when I tried to migrate them, obviously it failed.

In order to correct this, I'm assuming I need to take an older copy of the CoreData files, use them to replace the current ones and use the existing *xcdatamodels*, or do I have to create a new *xcdatamodel* and do another lightweight migration using the previous and new *xcdatamodels*?

Comment: Did you version the model before you made the changes each time? Sounds like that should be all that's required

Comment: I don't understand exactly what "version the model" means... I created a new xcdatamodel, made my changes, and then used MR to do the lightweight migration.  Everything worked as it should.  Then, I found a few errors in the new xcdatamodel that I need to correct, and it just went bonkers during the run.

Comment: I just added the attribute to the current (new) xcdatamodel, and it works!  Wain, please rewrite your comment as an answer and I'll give you the points (if you need them).

Comment: If you are going to trust your data to lightweight migrations, then you should understand what is going on, and since you don't know what "version the model" means, you should get some more basic information.  Here is the place to start: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html